# Chen notation to crow's foot

Tags: erd, database-diagrams

How do I illustrate relationships which has an attribute in chen notation to crows foot notation?

Example:

[image]

There is an attribute "quantity" in the relation. How do I draw that in crow's foot notation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want an [*intersection entitiy*](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ebernatja/crowsfoot.html):

> Intersection entities are used in the resolution of a many to many relationship. This resolution is done in order to store additional information which doesn’t fit into the attribute list of either entity in the M:M relationship.

See the Class entity below.

[image: Example of an intersection entity]

---

[Image source](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ebernatja/crowsfoot.html).